# ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform() on Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, e2e-testing

I am working on e2e UI testing with Selenium and using the Chrome driver.
My OS is macOS Big Sur.
I am testing the UI of the new upgraded website.
I can access the remote website needed to be tested on my laptop at any time.
I used the below method to affect the mouse cursor's hovering on a specific element in the UI.

```
def mouse_hover(driver, locator):
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

but ActionChains (driver). move_to_element (element). perform () method is making an attribute error like below on Jenkins.
I made sure this method works on my local without any issues.

```
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py:273: in move_to_element
    self.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to(to_element)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <selenium.webdriver.common.actions.pointer_actions.PointerActions object at 0x7f04f2a7a610>
element = <selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver.EventFiringWebElement object at 0x7f04f2ab66d0>
x = None, y = None

    def move_to(self, element, x=None, y=None):
        if not isinstance(element, WebElement):
>           raise AttributeError("move_to requires a WebElement")
E           AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/pointer_actions.py:42: AttributeError
```

I have tried to trigger the job on Jenkins many times but have always got the same result of this kind of error.

What alternative approach can affect the above method without any issue on Jenkins?
Anybody who has mastered using Jenkins can let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: More information was needed to debug this problem. Is the setup of Selenium the same as your local environment? Can you open the web site on your test machine? 
It would be helpful to print the `element` with `pprint` to console before raise error so that we can have more information to debug.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Share the `HTML` source for  this `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)`  element

Comment: Hi Akzy,
unfortunately, that's my company's internal website, and I am using the company's URL for testing.
For helping your understanding, I attached my screen shot.